# Vim does not apply some settings from .vimrc

Tags: vim

My .vimrc has a string "set tabstop=4", but it doesn't apply when i open something, for example, python file. Here's my full .vimrc:

```
cnoremap Q q
au! BufWritePost .vimrc source %
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set smarttab
set expandtab
set softtabstop=4
set autoindent
"set syntax=off
set t_co=256
```

strace says vim reads /home/user/.vimrc, and he really reads this file, for example, `cnoremap` works, he replaces :Q by :q as expected, but if i, for example, uncomment `set syntax=off`, it does not apply. 
Also, `vim -V2` says next:

```
...
считывание сценария "$HOME/.vimrc"
Поиск "syntax/off.vim syntax/off/*.vim" в "/home/user/.vim,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim80,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/home/user/.vim/after"
not found in 'runtimepath': "syntax/off.vim syntax/off/*.vim"
...
```

Of course, i thought, it was something with options. But if i made in editor `:so $MYVIMRC`, he applies all settings!

Right now i live with bash alias vim="vim -S ~/.vimrc", and in verbose mode he applies .vimrc without errors and works as expected, but that's weird solution.

What could be wrong here? And why vim does not apply tabstop/syntax from .vimrc?

Output of `:verb set ts`

```
tabstop=8
        В последний раз опция изменена в /usr/share/vim/vim80/ftplugin/python.vim
```

Output of :scriptnames

```
1: /etc/vimrc
  2: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/syntax.vim
  3: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/synload.vim
  4: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/syncolor.vim
  5: /usr/share/vim/vim80/filetype.vim
  6: /usr/share/vim/vimfiles/ftdetect/dockerfile.vim
  7: /usr/share/vim/vimfiles/ftdetect/nginx.vim
  8: /usr/share/vim/vimfiles/ftdetect/stp.vim
  9: /usr/share/vim/vim80/ftplugin.vim
 10: ~/.vimrc
 11: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
 12: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/gzip.vim
 13: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/logiPat.vim
 14: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/manpager.vim
 15: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/matchparen.vim
 16: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
 17: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/rrhelper.vim
 18: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/spellfile.vim
 19: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
 20: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/tohtml.vim
 21: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
 22: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
 23: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/python.vim
 24: /usr/share/vim/vim80/ftplugin/python.vim
```

Comment: vi.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @kamish Could you post the output of the command `:scriptnames`? If you want to capture it, you can use the `:redir` command (see `:h :redir`).

Comment: @kamish Also, what is the output of `:verb set ts?` ?

Comment: @user852573 Yes! Now i see.
:verb set ts

tabstop=8
        В последний раз опция изменена в /usr/share/vim/vim80/ftplugin/python.vim

Comment: @kamish This is a filetype plugin which probably sets the local value of your `tabstop` option. If you want to override this, you could write `setlocal tabstop=4` inside `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim`. You can create the file and the missing directories if needed. Otherwise, you could add an autocmd inside your vimrc listening to the `FileType` event to do the same thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the output of the command `:verbose set tabstop?` in a python buffer is:

```
tabstop=8
        В последний раз опция изменена в /usr/share/vim/vim80/ftplugin/python.vim
```

It means that the filetype plugin `/usr/share/vim/vi80/ftplugin/python.vim` sets the value of your `'tabstop'` option, local to the current python buffer, with `8` while you want `4`.

Your setting `set tabstop=4` doesn't take effect in a python buffer, because a local value has priority over a global one.

If you want to override this, you could create the file `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim` and write inside:

```
setlocal tabstop=4
```

Or you could add the following autocmd inside your `vimrc`:

```
augroup my_python_settings
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType python setlocal tabstop=4
augroup END
```

Comment: Also, /usr/share/vim/vim80/ftplugin/python.vim overrided  `syntax` option, so i overwrote him too and **it works**. Thank you!

Comment: I forced the value in this file too, but `aide` or intrusion tools will warn you that the file was altered... So not a great solution in the end.

Comment: Building on your suggestion I added a `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim` with only `source ~/.vimrc` in it. Forces vimrc to be reloaded after the script that clobbers my settings - resetting them to what I want.

Answer (score 1):

You may have the issue referred here:
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=864074

The solution is to uncomment the following line in `/etc/vim/vimrc` (by removing the `"` at the beginning of the line):

`let g:skip_defaults_vim = 1`

For me it was the `set mouse=a` which forced the Visual mode in vim 8.0, and didn't in vim 7.4.